# Angular 6 cannot get item from array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-http

I am building app which shows amazon products :

```
showProducts(){
    this.search.getProducts().subscribe
    ((data: any) => {
        this.list = data['hydra:member'];
        this.prices = data.lowestPrices.Amazon.newItem;
        console.log('Objects', this.list);
        console.log('Prices', this.prices);
    });

}
```

this.list in console :

[image]

this.prices in console :

> Cannot read property 'Amazon' of undefined

**How to get lowest prices of Amazon properly ?**

Comment: Isn't that an `Array`? go the index first and then retrieve the prop

Comment: Example would help

Comment: Try data[0]['lowestPrices']['Amazon]

Comment: data[index].lowestPrices.Amazon.newItem; use this

Comment: Like: `data`[0].lowestPrices.Amazon.newItem;` but now this would depened which index you want to access

Comment: I want all data items lowestPrices

Comment: @Angulandy2 So you want `this.prices` to be an array of all lowest prices?

Comment: I want to get all lowestPrices of all products - that means with FR value.

Comment: Then you have write a loop for the same.

Comment: @Angulandy2: I understand that, how you want to store it? is `this.prices` an array of all lowest prices?

Comment: You need to iterate every item of the array...

Comment: Yes i want that + country that means I need to store FR, IT , EN too as you see.

Comment: `data['hydra:member'][index].Amazon.newItem` is not a number but an object having `FR` property containing a price in euro. Since other data is not shown there maybe a newItem instance having `EN` and `GBP` property that has a different value than Euro. Without knowing the possible data there is no way to know the lowest price.

Comment: @Angulandy2 Tell me, `this.list = data['hydra:member'];` works for you?

Comment: Thanks for comments did it!

Comment: `can't get Amazon of undefined` means that data does not have a `lowestPrices` property but since you didn't post data or a sample of it there is no way of knowing if you may have misspelled the property name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Array map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), to iterate over the array and populate your properties
For Example:

```
this.prices = data['hydra:member'].map(elem => elem.lowestPrices.Amazon.newItem;);
```

Comment: which is better - for(i) or .map ?

Comment: Saves space is the only better thing I would say then

Comment: @Angulandy2 I am sorry just read this: https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7

Comment: @Angulandy2: You can even see this: https://github.com/dg92/Performance-Analysis-JS It seems the performance of a `for loop` and a `map` dependes upon the data size we are iterating over

Answer (score 2):

You're accessing an array `[]`. Arrays have indexes `[0]->[n]`

In your example it would be

```
showProducts(){
 this.search.getProducts().subscribe
 ((data: any) => {
  this.list = data['hydra:member'];
  this.prices = data['hydra:member'][0].lowestPrices.Amazon.newItem;
  console.log('Objects', this.list);
  console.log('Prices', this.prices);
});
```

for the first item.

You'll have to write a loop for each item of data for every information

Comment: Cannot get newItem of undefined.

Comment: I used it : data['hydra:member'].Amazon.newItem;

Comment: this.prices = data['hydra:member'][0].lowestPrices.Amazon.newItem; worked for me

Comment: How you are accessing it in html file??